Alternative algorithm for quantum phase estimation problem
The Quantum Phase estimation problem is stated below:
Input: Given $U$ as a unitary operator acting on an m-qubit register. If $| \psi \rangle$ is an eigenvector of $U$, then U$| \psi\rangle$ =  $e^{ 2\pi i \theta}\left|\psi \right\rangle $ for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.
Task: Estimate $\theta$ within $\epsilon$ approximation.
Resource cost:

How the number of (required) qubits scales with $\epsilon$.

How the circuit depth scales as $\epsilon$ (and qubits).


Wikipedia mentions an algorithm due to Kitaev (link). It uses controlled $U$ operations followed by QFT (detailed here). It costs $O(\log(1/\varepsilon))$ additional qubits and $O(\log(1/\Delta)/\varepsilon)$ controlled rotation of $U$. This is known to be optimal.
My query:

Are there other alternative algorithms to solve the same problem?


My motivation to ask the question: Kitaev's algorithm (QPE) was used (as a subroutine) in the HHL algorithm to solve the quantum linear system problem(QLSP). But later on, other techniques, like Childs et al. and Costa et al., used different methods to improve the $\epsilon$ dependency of the algorithm to optimal. Each of them is solving the same problem but in various styles.


The quantum phase estimation has a couple of parts: (1) state preparation to prepare the initial eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$, (2) Hamiltonian simulation to execute controlled versions of $U=\exp(-iHt)$ on this $|\psi\rangle$, and (3) the inverse Fourier transform to put the phases into the ancilla clock control register. The Hamiltonian simulation was optimized even after HHL's breakthrough paper; optimizing the iQFT has also been considered (but, Coppersmith's circuit is pretty good as it is).

@Mark, I agree. Kitaev construction ('Hamiltonian simulation+iQFT') has been well-optimized. I wondered if an alternative construction to reach the same goal (phase estimation) exists in the literature that does not necessarily rely on HamSim+iQFT.

@Mark, I find 'natural' to think of HamSim+iQFT combination to retrieve the phase. But, its $O(1/{\epsilon})$ dependency of gate complexity has been discouraging. Mostly in those algorithms where poly(log(1/${\epsilon}$)) is desired.
